# How to query for an entire day with timestamp values in Firestore

Tags: flutter, date, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have a firestore collection 'orders' whose documents has a timeStamp value. I want to filter documents of that collection based on timeStamp. For example, filter orders placed on July 1 ,2022.
I pass date value got from Datepicker as DateTime. The query i formed is

```
_db.collection('orders')
        .where('driverId', isEqualTo: sp.getString('uid'))
        .where('timeStamp', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(pickedDate!))
        .get().then((querySnapshot){
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
        orders.add(element.data());
      });
      print(orders.length);
    });
```

The problem is i'm getting orders from July 1 till today since i have given **isGreaterThanOrEqualTo**. But if i give **isEqualTo**,it returns nothing. Means it takes **01-07-2022 00:00:00** i guess. So **what is the correct query to get orders on a selected date**?

Comment: hi  
Azhagappan Kathiresan . I am unable to filter the value . Could you please help me out? I am using this command to filter the activities from firebase collections. finalRef = finalRef
                  .where('operatingStatus', isEqualTo: 'Open')
                  .where('endDate',
                      isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(
                          DateTime.parse('2022-02-06 00:00:00')))
                  .where('endDate',
                      isLessThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(
                          DateTime.parse('2022-12-30 00:00:00')));

Comment: I am getting empty  value [].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Timestamp` objects in Firestore are very specific points in time, with a microsecond precision. So if you want to match all timestamps for an entire day, that is a **range** of timestamp values.

The typical approach is to create a timestamp of one day later, and then add that to the second clause needed for the range:

```
_db.collection('orders')
    .where('driverId', isEqualTo: sp.getString('uid'))
    .where('timeStamp', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(pickedDate!))
    .where('timeStamp', isLessThan: timestampOfStartOfNextDay)
```